# Vue-Owl-Carousel not working when using Loop

Tags: vue.js

Vue-Owl-Carousel workign fine using the basic model :

```
<carousel>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?1">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?2">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?3">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any?4">
</carousel>
```

But when i use a loop on  , the Carousel broke and shows all slides in column.

```
<carousel> // Not Working
 <img v-for="slide in slides" :src="getslide(slide)">
</carousel>

<carousel> // Not Working
 <template  v-for="slide in slides"><img :src="getslide(slide)"></template>
</carousel>

<carousel> // Not Working, the error is with v-for..
<img v-for="slide in slides" src="/slide.png">
</carousel>
```

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: I tested and it seems work as expected. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-owl-carousel-demo-g13k7
How many items do you have in `slides`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
<div v-if="slides.length > 0">
<carousel>
 <img v-for="slide in slides" :src="getslide(slide)">
</carousel>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using axios to get data to the slides array from the database?. If so the template of vue is being rendered before the data is received in the array causing the carousel not to work. you can re render the vue component and it will work. I had same problem and re-rendering the vue solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-if="slides.length > 0">
<carousel>
 <img v-for="slide in slides" :src="getslide(slide)">
</carousel>
</div
```

code worked for me :)

Comment: On "code worked for me :)": It is assumed that the code you post as an answer *does work*; otherwise you shouldn't post. So better remove that statement and instead **explain** what your code does (how it works).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just check if your slides data is true

try this code :

```
<carousel v-if="slides">
   <img v-for="slide in slides" :src="slide.png">
</carousel>
```